# I am using bootstrap grid system to divide row in 11 and 1. but the home-logo in last col is not showing as expected. It is showing in the 1st col

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

see the home icon in 1st col over logo image. I want icon in the last col
[image]
I have added logo image in col-md-11 and home icon in col-md-1. but home icon is getting overlapped with the first col of col md-11.

```
    <div class="container-fluid logo-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-11"><!--for logo img-->
                            <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-1 home-icon"><!--for home icon-->
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--Logo section ends-->
```

Comment: Does the problem occur at all browser widths or only narrower ones?

Comment: for desktop its like this. for narrower width the icon is coming below the container in the first col only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cause of that scenario is that the contents of one of your columns are wider than the column.  This forces that column to be wider than the width specified by Bootstrap which breaks the Bootstrap column layout - causing the line break you are seeing.

The easiest way to resolve this is to remove the contents of all columns and then put them back one at a time.  You will quickly see which column has content that is causing the problem.

Comment: but i have one image that is definitely smaller that col-md-11

Comment: As you suggested I did rewrite the code. And its working. Thanks. But I didnt get where was the problem?.